# code to bring back DateTimePicker, radiobutton from DataGridVeiw to edit

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Cant figure out code for bringing back datetimepickers value and radiobuttons value to edit. what can i add there?

help would be really appreciated have a deadline in the morning >_<

```css
   private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataScreen.SelectedRows.Count > 0) // make sure user select at least 1 row 
            {
                name = dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value + string.Empty;
                Gender = dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
                DateOfBirth = dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
                Address = dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;
                MedicalHistory = dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value + string.Empty;
                BloodType = dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value + string.Empty;

                txtName.Text = name; txtAddress.Text = Address;
                txtMedicalHistory.Text = MedicalHistory;
                txtBloodType.Text = BloodType;

            }

            
        }
```

here

Comment: to avoid typing again i copy pasted and forgot to change that part. thankyouu!! but i still cant find a proper code for datetimepicker and radio button to get back properly. what do you think i can add there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTimePicker` control accepts a `DateTime` value, you can assign it this way:

```
myDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
myDateTimePicker.Value = new DateTime(2019, 1, 24);
myDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Parse(dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value);
```

`CheckBox` control accepts a `boolean` value:

```
myCheckBox.Checked = true;
myCheckBox.Checked = false;
cbMale.Checked = dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value == "Male";
cbFemale.Checked = dataScreen.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value == "Female";
```